# Multivariate correlation filters

Tags: python, stat, chi-squared, eda

How to identify the correlation between the association between two categorical features with the target variable.

For example:

If three features with me 2 categorical and 1 target variable
While identifying the correlation of each feature with the target variable using the chi-square test I am not able to find a strong relationship. So I thought to use the combination of these two feature and check if there exists a correlation with the target variable but I am confused if we can use the chi-square test for such cases or some other methods can be used?

For example:

```
ct_reloc_status = pd.crosstab(df_offer_details['percentage_hike_offered_bin'].sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1),
    [df_offer_details['Candidate relocation status'].sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1), 
            df_offer_details['Acceptance status'].sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1)])
ct_reloc_status

# we carry out a contingency test to check whether there is a correlation with the target variable 
# and relocation status 
H0 = "There is no relationship between Relocation status and Acceptance status"
Ha = "There is a relationship between Relocation status and Acceptance status"

stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(ct_reloc_status)
print('p-value: ',p)

prob = 0.95
critical = chi2.ppf(prob, dof)
print('probability=%.3f, critical=%.3f, stat=%.3f' % (prob, critical, stat))

if abs(stat) >= critical :
    print(f'''Since p-value {p} < 0.05 we reject null hypothesis: {H0}.Thus alternate hypothesis: {Ha} holds good ''')
else:
    print(f'Fail to reject null hypothesis {H0}')

Result:


p-value:  0.019814129159194147
probability=0.950, critical=28.869, stat=32.380
Since p-value 0.019814129159194147 < 0.05 we reject the null hypothesis: There is no relationship between Relocation status and Acceptance status.Thus alternate hypothesis: There is a relationship between Relocation status and Acceptance status holds good
```

But I am not sure whether this is the right approach